# How to Eject a Flash drive in Batch or Vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to eject my flash drive when i type eject into a command prompt, i have a shell of a code, but i don't have the actual code to eject it.

UNLOCK

```
@echo off
echo '
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p

if %password%==Eject goto EJECT

:EJECT

^if EXIST "D:\Some file in the Flash drive" goto D-DRIVE

:D-DRIVE

^code that ejects the D drive
```

after that bit i need the eject code

Comment: How about: SuperUser:[Remove USB device from command line](http://superuser.com/questions/443162/remove-usb-device-from-command-line)

Comment: You can also use - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to comment that same thing that mojo did above at about the same time.  However, after testing, it seems that scripting `diskpart` to dismount my own removable drives prevents them from automatically re-acquiring a drive letter the next time they're plugged in.  I had to go to Disk Management and re-assign a drive letter when re-plugging.  I'm sure that's not what you want.  Scripting a dismount with Win32_Volume [like this guy did](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/417345-powershell-script-to-eject-usb-device) had the same unfortunate side effect.

Playing with `hotplug.dll` [like this guy did](https://superuser.com/a/486705/204705) wasn't much help either, with Windows reporting that the type of drive wasn't a removable drive.

No, the most reliable, least side-effect-y method that doesn't require 3rd party utilities is to invoke the "Eject" verb from a "My Computer"-ish context.  Here's a solution involving a batch / JScript hybrid script:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end   /* JScript ignores this multiline comment

:: dismount.bat
:: safely dismounts all removable drives

@echo off
setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"

goto :EOF

:: end batch portion / begin JScript portion */

// DriveType=1 means removable drive for a WScript FSO object.
// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys4ctaz0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

// NameSpace(17) = ssfDRIVES, or My Computer.
// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

var oSH = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application'),
FSO = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
removableDriveType = 1,
ssfDRIVES = 17,
drives = new Enumerator(FSO.Drives);

while (!drives.atEnd()) {
    var x = drives.item();
    if (x.DriveType == removableDriveType) {
        oSH.NameSpace(ssfDRIVES).ParseName(x.DriveLetter + ':').InvokeVerb('Eject');
        while (x.IsReady)
            WSH.Sleep(50);
    }
    drives.moveNext();
}
```

Also, you can invoke the "Eject" verb from the same namespace using PowerShell [in a similar way](https://serverfault.com/a/580298), but you'll still need to `Start-Sleep` to prevent the ps thread from exiting before the drive has been ejected.  I leave that as an exercise for the O.P. if he prefers PowerShell over WScript.

---

**Edit:** If you want to define a specific drive to dismount in your batch script, do it like this:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end   /*

@echo off
setlocal

set "drive=F:"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%drive%"

goto :EOF

::  */

var oSH = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application'),
    FSO = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    drive = WSH.Arguments(0);

oSH.NameSpace(17).ParseName(drive).InvokeVerb('Eject');
while (FSO.GetDrive(drive).IsReady) WSH.Sleep(50);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in VBScript or is java the only way? i prefer simply way to eject, if that's the simplest way then i'll take it.

Comment: That's not Java. It's not even JavaScript, although that'd be a closer association. It's JScript, a close cousin to VBScript. Yes, it [can be done with VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220273/1683264). I just used JScript because it's much more graceful to run a JScript snippet as a batch hybrid than it is to echo chunks of VBscript out to a separate vbs file. No this is not the only way. It can actually be done with much fewer lines of JScript code as well if I just arbitrarily `WSH.Sleep(1000)` or similar, but that might cause issues if there's an open handle blocking the Eject action.

Comment: what is the ending for JScript

Comment: Nevermind that last comment, how would you make it eject just the F drive

Comment: I don't know it I'm being stupid or something, but it's not working. can you give me a base code or something to help

Comment: @JonathanVijuMathai See edited answer.  This will be the last update I perform on this answer, as any further revisions are likely to be too specific to be of any benefit to future users.  S.O. is not intended to be used as a free coding service.