# Remove usb drive using cli, on success remove turn off the windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wondering to make a batch file that have purposed like this :

when a usb drive that ejected on my notebook is succesfully unmount, I want to make my windows is shutdown.

So, I use [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html).

Assumed, I mounted my flash drive to E, I use this command

```
RemoveDrive.exe E: -L
```

it gives me message like this :

```
Removing 'My drive'(E:)
success
```

Now, I was wondering to make a batch file (.bat), when success, it execute 'shutdown / s'. if failed, it gives me just a message error.  How come ?
Amy help it so appreciated.

Edit :
based this web : [FAQ](ftp://mzosh19.org.ua/software/PortableUSB/PortableApps/Total%20Commander%208.1/Utilites/DevEject/RemoveDrive.txt)
it said :

```
0 - successfully removed a device
1 - device identified but not removed
2 - device not found or parameters are invalid
4 - RemoveDrive.exe located on the drive to remove -> temporary copy 
    created and executed
```

so this is my code so far :

```
@ECHO OFF
set def="0"
SET /P uname=Enter the drive (letter:): 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
    RemoveDrive.exe "%uname%" -L
if %ERRORLEVEL% == def
  shutdwon /s
else
  echo 'Something have problem'
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO Please enter your drive's name! 
:End
```

if success or failed, it still gives me the syntax of command is inicnorrect message

Comment: What is that error-message of the message error? And why do I ask?

Comment: let say, it invalid drive : , the message is 'abort'.

Comment: FWIW, you can invoke the "Eject" verb via WSH's `Shell.Application` object to safely dismount removable drives.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27234424/1683264

Comment: 1) `shutdwon`? 2) `%errorlevel%` will never be `def` (possibly it will be `%def%`). 3) No parantheses with `if`-`else` statement used.

Answer (score 0):

As per `if` command syntax and explanation in [Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335.aspx):

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == def (
  shutdown /s
) else (
  echo 'Something have problem'
)
```